# How to automatically protect all the commands passed in an argument?

Tags: amsmath, write, protected-macro

I need to write to an auxfile some mathematical formulas.

The following MWE does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newwrite\filehandle
\newcommand{\addToFile}[1]{\immediate\write\filehandle{#1}}

\begin{document}

\immediate\openout\filehandle=\jobname.test
\addToFile{$\sum_{k=1}^n k$}
\immediate\closeout\filehandle

\input{\jobname.test}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automatically protect all the commands used in the argument `#1` of `\addToFile`?

I won't be the user of this file: that's why I am looking for an automatic solution.

PS: The problem here comes from the package `amsmath`.

Comment: `\unexpanded{  whatever ...}`

Comment: Can you make it an answer so I can accept it? Thanks. Otherwise, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can surround the argument with `\unexpanded{....}`

Answer (score 1):

With `expl3` no expansion is done unless explicitly requested with `\iow_now:Nx`; using `\iow_now:Nn` will do nothing to the input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \g_colas_filehandle_iow

\NewDocumentCommand{\openFile}{m}
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \g_colas_filehandle_iow { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\closeFile}{}
 {
  \iow_close:N \g_colas_filehandle_iow
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addToFile}{m}
 {
  \iow_now:Nn \g_colas_filehandle_iow { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\openFile{\jobname.test}
\addToFile{$\sum_{k=1}^n k$}
\closeFile

\input{\jobname.test}

\end{document}
```

The contents of the `\jobname.test` file will be

```
$\sum _{k=1}^n k$
```